# In MySQL, how do I order by the number of times a specific instance appears?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I'm creating a View in MySQL that will group the titles of movies by the number of times they have been rented, in descending order. So far, I have this:

```
CREATE VIEW number_of_rentals as
SELECT title
FROM film
JOIN inventory ON film.film_id=inventory.film_id
JOIN rental ON inventory.inventory_id=rental.inventory_id;
```

Which gives me a result like this:

Movie1 
Movie1 
Movie1 
Movie1 
Movie2 
Movie2 
Movie3 
Movie3 
Movie3

What I need is to display a list that looks like this (the actual count does not need to be displayed):

Movie1 (because it appears 4 times in the list) 
Movie3 (because it appears 3 times in the list) 
Movie2 (because it appears 2 times in the list)

That is, each individual movie in descending order of the number of times it appears in the initial list. I'm having trouble figuring out how to count the number of times each individual movie appears. Any tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT f.title 
FROM film f
JOIN inventory i ON f.film_id = i.film_id 
JOIN rental r ON i.inventory_id = r.inventory_id
group by f.title
order by count(*) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY`:

```
CREATE VIEW number_of_rentals as
SELECT title, count(*) as rentals
FROM film
JOIN inventory ON film.film_id=inventory.film_id
JOIN rental ON inventory.inventory_id=rental.inventory_id
GROUP BY film.title;
```

This will give you title and rental count on one line for each title.

For output of sorted order use

```
SELECT * 
FROM number_of_rentals
ORDER BY rentals;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SELECT in your view should probably look very similar to this:

```
SELECT title, count(title) as rentals
FROM film 
JOIN inventory ON film.film_id=inventory.film_id 
JOIN rental ON inventory.inventory_id=rental.inventory_id
GROUP BY title
ORDER BY count(title) DESC;
```

Here's a basic [sqlfiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ba61/9) that may show similar results.   I hope this helps.